# Регулярное выражение для поиска как минимум 2-х букв в строке

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста регулярное выражение для поиска как минимум 2-х букв в строке. Буквы могут находится где угодно, не обязательно идти подрят.

Comment: Буквы не обязательно могут повторяться, так же не важен регистр и тому подобное. Главное что бы их было как минимум 2 в строке, и не важно каких и в каком порядке расположенных.

Пример (javascript):
/регулярка/i.test('w89u7'); /*должно вернуть true*/
/регулярка/i.test(';Te153#-00'); /*должно вернуть true*/

Comment: Решения найдены:

/(?=(?:.*?[a-z){2})/i

/.*?[a-z].*?[a-z].*/i

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
.*(\w).*(\1.*)+
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/coder13/Q4jL7/

Comment: Вроде ж не обязательно одинаковых букв?

Comment: @VladD: Ну я логически рассуждал. Обычно ищут дубликаты, а фраза "не обязательно идти подрят", говорит сама за себя.

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено: `(?=(?:.*?[a-zA-Z]){2})`

Comment: Преобразовал Ваш комментарий в ответ, примите, чтобы закрыть вопрос.

Comment: А почему тогда так сложно? Почему не просто `\w.*\w`?

Comment: И самый производительный вариант для полноты картины :)  

    \w\W*+\w